# Dealing with quotation marks in PHP code and JSON

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am building in PHP a complex JSON array result by doing several queries into a DB and then pushing the data into an array and finally json_encode -ing it using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK. I get all the numbers arrays clean, without quotation marks. The problem is that the sets of name/value pairs

```
"{y: 39,ratio: 150}",...,"{y: 40,ratio: 364}"
```

have the outside quotation marks which is not acceptable in HighCharts. Here is a snippet of the PHP code:

```
$series = array();
$series['name'] = 'Trend';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$series['data'][] = 'y: ' . $row['A'] . ',ratio: ' . round($row['A'] / $row['B'] * 100, 0) . '}';
}
$result = array();
array_push($result,$series);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
array_push($result,$category);
```

How can I get rid of the quotation marks and see as a result the following:

```
{y: 39,ratio: 150},...,{y: 40,ratio: 364}
```

Comment: I would need help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
$series['data'][] = 'y: ' . $row['A'] . ',ratio: ' . round($row['A'] / $row['B'] * 100, 0) . '}';
```

Replace the code above with these:

```
$series['data'][] = array("y" => $row['A'],
    "ratio" => round($row['A'] / $row['B'] * 100, 0));
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Sir! It did solve the issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I had to use help to find out how to accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $series['data'][] = (object)array(
     'y' => $row['A'],
     'ratio' => round($row['A'] / $row['B'] * 100, 0)
   );
 }
```

Then, you can

```
print json_encode($series);
```

Comment: I simplified and significantly obfuscated the question (the whole code is complex), so getting the answer is not that straightforward. In any case, if I do a print json_encode($series), w/o JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, then other arrays of pure numbers have them quoted. So JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK help with the pure numbers arrays, but the arrays of name/value pairs each are flanked by quotation marks.